# How do I redirect the homepage of a domain to another page using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, dns, url-rewriting

I have a website that has three domains pointing to it (.com, .co.uk, .fr).

The site has the same content for it apart from the homepage/landing page. I searched online and tried about 10 different pieces of code, I would really appreciate some help.

So I would like to redirect:
 http://www.example.co.uk to http://www.example.co.uk/uk-homepage/
 http://www.example.eu to http://www.example.eu/eu-homepage/

**Additional info**
The homepage is index.php

.com will show the default index.php, so no need to change that.
They are all using the same website directory and files. So *.eu/about/ is the exact same as *.com/about/. I just need the homepage for 2 domains to show a different page on the same site.

I don't want .eu or .co.uk to revert to .com. They both keep their domain in the address bar and I'd like to keep it that way. 
So the following code will not work.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.eu [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.eu [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

**301 wont do the job**
I have 301 working for old pages but 301 wont work for the domains as it does not work when I put the full url with domain in. The 301 only work for /old-contact/ /new-contect/. But they won't work for http://www.example.co.uk/old-contact/ http://www.example.co.uk/new-contact/. So http://www.example.co.uk/index.php http://www.example.co.uk/uk-homepage/ won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these rules:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /uk-homepage/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.eu$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /ey-homepage/ [L,R=301]
```

Make sure to keep these 2 rules right below `RewriteEngine On` line.